# Issues With Ordering Array from Greatest To Least

Tags: arrays, vb.net, random, drag-and-drop

Below you will see what I have for making a random array. I am needing to order the items from greatest to least and then be able to put them into textboxes according to the class the user has picked. This is for a DnD 4e ability generator. I need to be able to put the highest ability scores into the best suited field for that class.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim randstr As New Random

    'Dim a As Integer
    'Dim b As Integer
    'Dim c As Integer
    'Dim d As Integer
    'Dim h As Integer
    'Dim f As Integer


    'a = randstr.Next(3, 18)
    'b = randstr.Next(3, 18)
    'c = randstr.Next(3, 18)
    'd = randstr.Next(3, 18)
    'h = randstr.Next(3, 18)
    'f = randstr.Next(3, 18)

    Static randomNumberGenerator As New System.Random


    Dim randomNumbers(6) As Integer ' Create the array

    Dim smallestNumber As Integer = 3 ' Set the lower bounds

    Dim largestNumber As Integer = 18 ' Set the upper bounds



    For i = 0 To 6 ' loop through each element in the array

        randomNumbers(i) = randomNumberGenerator.Next(smallestNumber, largestNumber)

    Next

    If CbClass.SelectedItem = "Fighter" Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You say you have an issue sorting the numbers,  but what is the issue? What code do you have for the sort routine a d what behaviour are you getting compared to what you want to get?  This needs to be edited into your question. Have a look here..  Cheers ...  [ask]

Comment: Very, very unclear what you are asking.  What is the expected outcome? What do you get instead? How is it wrong?  See [Ask]

Comment: I dont have the sorting part. I looked at some other code that done the same, but its nothing I am looking gor. What I need to do is order the array from highest to lowest and then be able to grab the each part of the array that I need and then output it into textboxes if they meet the requirements. Like if someone makes a fighter the highest stat needs to be strength. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will sort your array greatest to smallest - After this code..

```
For i = 0 To 6 ' loop through each element in the array

    randomNumbers(i) = randomNumberGenerator.Next(smallestNumber, largestNumber)

Next
```

add

```
Array.Sort(randomNumbers)
Array.Reverse(randomNumbers)
```

To add them to Textboxes

```
TextBox1.Text = randomNumbers(0).ToString
TextBox2.Text = randomNumbers(1).ToString
TextBox3.Text = randomNumbers(2).ToString
TextBox4.Text = randomNumbers(3).ToString
TextBox5.Text = randomNumbers(4).ToString
TextBox6.Text = randomNumbers(5).ToString
```

remembering of course to change the names of the above textboxes to whatever yours are called.

To set the stats for a character, you probably want something like this

```
If CbClass.SelectedItem = "Fighter" Then
    Strength = randomNumbers(0)
    Aglity = randomNumbers(1)
    Health = randomNumbers(2)
    Intellect = randomNumbers(3)
End If
```

and so on.

Comment: Ty sir just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the easiest way for you to generate and order your numbers:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Static randomNumberGenerator As New System.Random()

    Dim smallestNumber As Integer = 3 ' Set the lower bounds
    Dim largestNumber As Integer = 18 ' Set the upper bounds
    Dim randomNumbers() As Integer = _
        Enumerable _
            .Range(0, 6) _
            .Select(Function (x) randomNumberGenerator.Next(smallestNumber, largestNumber + 1)) _
            .OrderByDescending(Function (x) x) _
            .ToArray()

    ' Rest of your code here

End Sub
```

Do keep in mind that calling `randomNumberGenerator.Next(smallestNumber, largestNumber + 1)` that the `+ 1` is important as the second parameter to this call is an **exclusive** upper bound.

When you run this code the `randomNumbers` array will contain something like this:

[image: randomNumbers]

You can then just assign the values like `Dim x = randomNumbers(0)`, etc.